# Scraping a table with row labels in Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a table from a website that has row labels.  I'm able to get the actual data from the table, but I have no idea how to get the row labels as well.

Here is my code right now:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/dt-td/Rp-eng.cfm?TABID=2&LANG=E&A=R&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=01&GL=-1&GID=1341679&GK=1&GRP=1&O=D&PID=110719&PRID=10&PTYPE=109445&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2017&THEME=125&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0"
res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

html = res.read()

## parse with BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tables = bs.find_all("table")
table = tables[0]

df = pd.DataFrame()

rows = table.find_all("tr")

#extract the first column name (Employment income groups (18))
column_names = []
header_cells = rows[0].find_all("th") 

for cell in header_cells:
    header = cell.text
    header = header.strip()
    header = header.replace("\n", " ")
    column_names.append(header)

#extract the rest of the column names
header_cells = rows[1].find_all("th") 

for cell in header_cells:
    header = cell.text
    header = header.strip()
    header = header.replace("\n", " ")
    column_names.append(header)

#this is an extra label
column_names.remove('Main mode of commuting (10)')

#get the data from the table
data = []
for row in rows[2:]:

    ## create an empty tuple
    dt = ()

    cells = row.find_all("td")

    for cell in cells:
        ## dp stands for "data point"
        font = cell.find("font")

        if font is not None:
            dp = font.text
        else:
            dp = cell.text

        dp = dp.strip()
        dp = dp.replace("\n", " ")

        ## add to tuple
        dt = dt + (dp,)
    data.append(dt)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = column_names)
```

Creating the dataframe will give an error because the code above only extracts the cells with data points but does not extract the first cell of each row that contains the row label.

That is, there are 11 column names, but the tuples only have 10 values because it is not extracting the row label (ie, Total - Employment income) because they are of "th" type.

How can I get the row label and put it into the tuple as I process the rest of the data in the table?

Thank you for your help.

(The table I am trying to scrape is on this [site](http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/dt-td/Rp-eng.cfm?TABID=2&LANG=E&A=R&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=01&GL=-1&GID=1341679&GK=1&GRP=1&O=D&PID=110719&PRID=10&PTYPE=109445&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2017&THEME=125&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0) if it's not clear from the code)

Answer (score 1):

Use this `table.findAll('th',{'headers':'col-0'})` to find row labels

```
lab = []
labels = table.findAll('th',{'headers':'col-0'})
for label in labels:

    data = str(label.text).strip()
    data = str(data).split("($)Footnote", 1)[0]

    lab.append(data)
    #print(data)
```

**EDIT:**
Using pandas.read_html

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd  
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www12.statcan.gc.ca/census-recensement/2016/dp-pd/dt-td/Rp-eng.cfm?TABID=2&LANG=E&A=R&APATH=3&DETAIL=0&DIM=0&FL=A&FREE=0&GC=01&GL=-1&GID=1341679&GK=1&GRP=1&O=D&PID=110719&PRID=10&PTYPE=109445&S=0&SHOWALL=0&SUB=0&Temporal=2017&THEME=125&VID=0&VNAMEE=&VNAMEF=&D1=0&D2=0&D3=0&D4=0&D5=0&D6=0"
res = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

html = res.read()

## parse with BeautifulSoup
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

tables = bs.find_all("table")

df = (pd.read_html(str(tables)))[0]
#print(df)
columns = ['Employment income groups (18)','Total - Main mode of commuting','Car, truck or van','Driver, alone',
          '2 or more persons shared the ride to work','Driver, with 1 or more passengers',
         'Passenger, 2 or more persons in the vehicle','Sustainable transportation',
         'Public transit','Active transport','Other method']
df.columns = columns
```

Edit 2: Element wont be accesible by index because strings are not proper strings (Employment income groups (18) column labels). I have the edited the code again.

Comment: Thank you!  For the purposes of applying labels to rows in a dataframe table, is it better to get the label values out separately or as part of the loop that gets the rest of the cell data?   Also, could you explain the {'headers':'col-0'} bit?  I understand that it's checking for the word headers and col-0, which is in the source of the web page, but I don't understand the syntax.

Comment: see `<th id="row-1" headers="col-0" class="font-normal  text-left text-bottom">
        
        Total - Employment income
  </th>` and  this html 
   `<th id="col-0" class="text-bottom text-left" rowspan="2">Employment income groups (18)</th>`

Comment: @firehawk12- I have a better solution for u. I have edited the answer plz go through that :)